# Font short syntax for google fonts

Tags: css, fonts

For google fonts the font-family and font-weight are variables. The short syntax should be

```
font: 400 "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

But I get invalid property value,

Is there a way to declare just font-weight and font family in the short version? I want everything else to stay as it is (font style etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the font-size must be specified when using font shorthand.
`font: 400 12px "Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`
See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/ and http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font 
You'll need to use the good old font-weight and font-family instead of the shorthand.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, setting size to `100%` or `1em` may have an effect different from not setting it at all (when some other style sheet sets the font size).